# how to update date using phpmysql

Tags: php

This is how,i insert data into db,but now,i want a particular column to update,how do i do?

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("form", $con);


$sql="INSERT INTO Customer (Name, Address, City, Pincode, State, Country, Phone, Mobile, Fax, Email, Website, Notes)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[pincode]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[mobile]','$_POST[fax]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[url]','$_POST[notes]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Which column? Updated to what?

Comment: This code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Off topic: SO needs to warn users if they are saving edits to a question that has been edited already. (I would suggest it on meta, but my account is broken there.)

Answer (score 3):

A SQL update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE customers SET fieldname = newvalue WHERE id = '$id'
```

Complete syntax guide is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html.

Also, you might want to have a look at filtering any user input before sending it the database. Using [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is pretty much a necessity for security reasons.

Comment: YOu would seen the code ,i used to insert.Now,if there are n records ,i need to select one column and edit the data and put back them in to db.
Plz give me a snippet

Comment: If you're changing all of the columns to the same value, you could run "UPDATE customers SET fieldname = newvalue". If you need to edit each one individually, as far as I know you'll have to run a separate query for each record.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UPDATE` query in pace of the `INSERT`.

Something like:

```
$sql="UPDATE Customer SET Name = $new_name WHERE....";
```

Rest of the code remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use mysqli_query to avoid SQL injection and escape the post values as well as assign to your own valuables before inserting to the DB.

like;

```
 (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
```

to Update any column in your Mysql DB,

```
sql = "UPDATE customers SET columnname = newvalue WHERE id = '$id'";


if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con)) 
{ die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
 } 
$con->close;
```